# Unable to create Kubernetes cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are unable to create Kubernetes clusters in our Google Cloud project. It was working a few weeks ago. We keep getting the following error:

`Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for 'projects/<project code>/zones/us-central1-a'`

However, the role assigned to the user trying to create the cluster is `Project/Owner`, and the service account selected when creating the cluster has `Project/Editor`, which includes the `compute.zones.get` permission. Even if I give the service account `Project/Owner` it still gives the same error.

---

**EDIT**

When trying to create the cluster with `gcloud` we get a different (similar) error:

`Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects/<project code>/global/networks/default'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what went wrong, but the fix was to disable all the compute services, and then re-initialising the Kubernetes service.

Comment: I wanted to comment that yesterday, but I didn't found it as a good answer. this is just a workaround to make it work. I had similar problems with GCP when I'd changed settings and permissions... and I always get into that "fix"

Comment: how do you disable all compute services? or you mean "delete", because that is the only option I get from kubernetes engine

Answer (score 0):

You lack the cloudservices [service account](https://cloud.google.com//compute/docs/access/service-accounts#google_apis_service_account) in IAM.  A current workaround for this issue is to re-enable the Google Cloud Compute Engine API.

Comment: I get the error: Following service(s) depend on service(s) to be deactivated: container.googleapis.com,deploymentmanager.googleapis.com,replicapool.googleapis.com,replicapoolupdater.googleapis.com,resourceviews.googleapis.com

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to disable the Compute API due to an apparent dependency loop, but creating a new GCP project "fixed" this for me.